# Severe efficiency problems with generating combinations

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Given a positive integral number n, return a strictly increasing
>   sequence (list/array/string depending on the language) of numbers, so
>   that the sum of the squares is equal to n².
>
> If there are multiple solutions (and there will be), return the result
>   with the largest possible value:

Basically, a squared number deconstructed into smaller squares. However, my code only works for smalls numbers efficiently (20 being roughly the max for the first piece of code, 30~ for second) and is exponentially slower onwards. How can I develop the code?

I don't know enough about efficiency in a language and be able to apply to my code and I tried optimising it by reducing the memory usage by setting comb to take out any bits of irrelevant data for the one below

For the second piece of code I tried using recursion to solve my problem but it still is getting exponentially slower. Perhaps I need a new method? Much appreciated.

```
import itertools as it
from math import sqrt


def decompose(n):
    squares = [i ** 2 for i in range(1, n) if (i ** 2)/2 < n ** 2]
    comb = [list(i) for i in (reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + list(it.combinations(squares, x)),
                                     range(1, len(squares) + 1), [])) if sum(i) == n ** 2]
    print [int(sqrt(i)) for i in max(comb)]


decompose(20)
```

this was the first attempt, failed in efficiency so I tried this.

```
from math import sqrt
stuff = []


def decompose(a):
    def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
        s = sum(partial)

        if s == target:
            stuff.append(partial)
        if s >= target:
            return

        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            n = numbers[i]
            remaining = numbers[i+1:]
            subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])

    compare = 1
    large = None
    subset_sum([x**2 for x in range(1, a)], a**2)

    for y in stuff:
        if compare < y[-1]:
            compare = y[-1]
            large = y

    print [int(sqrt(o)) for o in large]


decompose(30)
```

Comment: For *n = 13*, both [5, 12] and [3, 4, 12] are solutions. Which one has the "largest possible value"?

Comment: That is a very good question that codewars has not specified, I assume it's the latter...hopefully

Comment: I suppose that [5, 12] is solution, since it is in lexicography order larger than [3, 4, 12] (looking on reversed sequences).